# Selenium python formatter test failed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-ide

I have used selenium ide to create tests and saved it as python script (webdriver). But when i run this using python. am getting some errors 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyUnit-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/unittest.py", line 273, in failUnlessEqual

This is the code that auto generated in Selenium IDE using python formatter.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import unittest, time, re

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.co.in/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_untitled(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").send_keys("testomg")
        try: self.assertEqual("testomg - Google Search", driver.title)
        except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert.text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

RESULT

E

```
ERROR: test_untitled (__main__.Untitled)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing2.py", line 40, in tearDown
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyUnit-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/unittest.py", line 273, in failUnlessEqual
    raise self.failureException, (msg or '%s != %s' % (first, second))
AssertionError: [] != ['testomg - Google Search != Google']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected failure of your test.

This line

```
try: self.assertEqual("testomg - Google Search", driver.title)
```

Is asserting that the title of the page you have visited should be "testomg - Google Search". It was actually "Google".

Your test is failing. Probably because you aren't pressing enter or clicking the search button after entering the search term into the Google search form

Try adding

```
driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfsa").click()
```

Just after you send the keys to the query box element.